# What is difference between node js require() and Rhino Shell load()?

Tags: javascript, java, requirejs

I am trying to load [ccxt.js](https://github.com/ccxt/ccxt) from rhino shell (working on a java project) but it just won't load.

**starting the shell:**

```
java -cp rhino1.7.12/lib/rhino-1.7.12.jar:. org.mozilla.javascript.tools.shell.Main
```

**loading ccxt:**

```
js> load('node_modules/r.js')
js> var ccxt = require(['ccxt/ccxt.js'])
js: "ccxt/ccxt.js", line 171: SyntaxError: invalid object initializer
js: module.exports = Object.assign ({ version, Exchange, exchanges: Object.keys (exchanges) }, exchanges, functions, errors)
js: .........................................^
js: "ccxt/ccxt.js", line 1: Compilation produced 1 syntax errors. at node_modules/r.js:2466
```

And when loaded same js in node js server, no problem there.

```
var ccxt = require("ccxt");
logger.logger.info('ccxt exchnges:'+ ccxt.exchanges);
```

How can I load such files in Rhino Shell ?

Comment: rhino js is javascript shell -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/Rhino  which is for interoperability with java

Comment: Looking at the error, it looks like Rhyno doesn't support object shorthand, or pretty much most of ESNext features..  https://mozilla.github.io/rhino/compat/engines.html  What you could do is grab `ccxt/ccxt.js` and transpile is on Babel's website..

Comment: Also, seen as you appear to be using node, you could maybe even setup some sort of build system using babel, to auto-cross compile ESNext features into Rhino..

Comment: sir i am working on android app which uses java

Comment: Yes, that's fine.  What I'm telling you to do is transpile  `ccxt/ccxt.js` into  ES5 Javascript that will work with Rhino.   Basically Rhino doesn't support modern JS syntax, and what babel will do is convert the Javascript into a version than Rhino should be able to understand.

Comment: i transpiled one file which is doing require() for many other js  files. can you tell me how to transpile whole module?

Comment: `transpile whole module?` You might find https://webpack.js.org/ might help here if you want it compile everything for you, the added bonus is that the JS files can also be bundled, and this might give you some performance improvements too.

Comment: tons of errors on loading bundled file. tried both webpack and browserify. "app/src/main/assets/js/bundling/ccxt.bundled.js", line 8753: missing } after function body
js: function subclass (BaseClass, classes, namespace = {}) {
js: ..................................................^
js: "app/src/main/assets/js/bundling/ccxt.bundled.js", line 1: Compilation produced 1355 syntax errors.
        at app/src/main/assets/js/node_modules/r.js:2466